# What's the best way to harvest organs from the Infernal Machine?

Tags: diablo-iii

It's clear that key farming will be an exercise on its own, but after key farming, what strategies are effective in farming the organs?

For example in Diablo 2 it was well known that you wanted to wait to open all 3 portals at the same time to take the randomness out of it, is that possible in Diablo 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just did 3 complete sets last night with my friends and here are some general tips to do this.

1. Depending on your dps, you may want to prepare some champions/elites near waypoints to 'restock' up on NV in between boss fights.  Since you NEED to maintain 5 stacks for any chance of the organ drop at all.
2. You'll want to fight on the highest MP you can tolerate at since each additional level grants a 10% chance of dropping an organ.
3. You can open up all 3 portals at the same time, you don't have to worry about portal placement like in d2 (raise your hand if you've borked yourself like I did by opening up 2 portals at the same place in D2), each portal shows up in a prearranged position.  They are arranged in a triangle.  When you use the inferno machine in the shack, one random portal will open up in one of the locations.  I recommend just opening 1 at a time though, in case you can't handle the boss on that MP or if the game crashes, so you don't waste 3 inferno machines.
4. Specific portal boss strategies:

   - Top portal: The Realm of Chaos - Ghom and Raknoth(drops **Devil's Fang**).  Go after Ghom first as he'll spawn his usual cloud of annoying stuff, and Raknoth will teleport around quite often during the fight so its easier to kill Ghom first.
   - Left portal: The Realm of Discord - King Leoric and Mahgda (drops **Writhing Spine**).  This fight is very annoying.  Mahgda's insect swarm hurts a LOT.  At the beginning of the fight, attack Mahgda first until she puts up her shield, then go after the Skeleton King.  Mahgda will keep her shield up for the rest of the fight until the skeleton king dies, making her slightly less annoying.  Also, she'll run around a lot, and try not to fight her while she's in a corner as she spawns arcane beams.
   - Right portal: The Realm of Turmoil - Siege Breaker and Zoltun Kulle(drops **Vengeful Eye**).  Kill seige breaker first since ZK loves to run around a lot.  When ZK puts up his annoying time bubble, make sure you lead seigebreaker out of it or your attacks will be severely slowed down.
5. Remember, these are considered full boss fights.  Don't hit that resurrect button (if you are playing with friends) as you'll be kicked out of the battle.  Try to get a res if possible.

Comment: as a side note, all these organs make me feel like I'm running an organ harvesting scheme or something..

Comment: I bet Maghda hates waking up in a bathtub full of ice

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to open all 3 portals at the same time in the Heretic's Abode found in New Tristram. There isn't much to say about organ farming otherwise.

Comment: This seems like it answers for Diablo 2, not 3.

Comment: does opening all 3 portals in 1 game guarantee unique organ drops like in diablo 2?

Comment: In each opened realm, you fight a different boss:
The Realm of Discord - King Leoric and Mahgda.
The Realm of Turmoil - Siege Breaker and Zoltun Kulle.
The Realm of Chaos - Ghom and Raknoth.
Each duo might drop a specific organ.
To avoid multiple drops of the same organ, you should open all 3 portals within the same game.

Comment: yes, this applies to diablo 3 as well