# How can I craft The Hellfire Ring?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the key wardens and where are my keys?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85978/where-are-the-key-wardens-and-where-are-my-keys)
>   [Where can I find the keys and the plans for the infernal machine?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89281/where-can-i-find-the-keys-and-the-plans-for-the-infernal-machine)

What are the components, where can I get them, and how much gold do I need to craft The Hellfire Ring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entire process is detailed pretty well on [the official blog](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/7597724/New_Event_The_Infernal_Machine-10_15_2012).  The basic steps are

1. In each Act, get 5 stacks of Nephalem Valor and then fight the Keywarden for a chance [to collect the keys/plan](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89281/where-can-i-find-the-keys-and-the-plans-for-the-infernal-machine). (You only need to get the plan once)
2. Give the Blacksmith 12,000 gold to construct the Portal Device.
3. [Use the Portal Device](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85979/whats-the-best-way-to-harvest-organs-from-the-infernal-machine) in Heretic's Abode to reach one of the Uber bosses and get a chance to collect an organ.
4. Purchase a recipe for the ring from Squirt for 2 million gold (only need to do this once)
5. Give all 3 organs to Shen along with 15,000 gold to construct a ring.

So its a minimum of 51,000 gold per ring (3 x 12000 + 15000), plus a one time cost of 2 million for the ring recipe.

Comment: Do you need one portal device for each boss?

Comment: @Back Yep.  So I guess I should adjust that gold figure.

Comment: Can I still do this if I have a level 70 characters?

Comment: @Jim It looks like you want to check out http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85978/where-are-the-key-wardens-and-where-are-my-keys-to-create-a-hellfire-ring-amulet for more updated info.